# rdp on two pcs in same network

Tags: networking, windows-8, router, remote-desktop

I've recently tried to add a *2nd PC* to my router, so that i can use RDP on this PC too. The *1st one* already works, as it's using the standard methods (default RDP port **3389**, etc.)

So, currently the *1st PC* is open for any connection, i can just connect to it with the external IP address. No problem.

The second PC however;

- I have added to my router listening to port **3390**
- I have changed the listening port to **3390** in *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber*
- I have checked if my Windows Firewall or AVG Firewall is blocking or disabling port **3390**
- I have tried to connect through *EXTERNAL_IP*:**3390** with RDP
- I have rebooted my router, and PC multiple times to double check.

And still, i can't get this thing working.

Any idea's?

**OS:** Windows 8.1

**Router:** Cisco EPC3928AD

Thanks in advance,

BBQ.

Comment: IIRC, port 3390 was no good with RDP, some sort of client limitation or something.

Comment: @DanielB Weird, cause almost any site i've searched on (even the microsoft support site) suggest to connect any second device with an incremented portnummer to 3389; 3390.

Comment: just to be sure, you router is forwarding 3390 to the IP of the 2nd pc?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8.1 does not have support for incomming RDP connections. You will need Windows 8.1 Pro to support incomming RDP connections. Upgrade to Windows 8.1 Pro and you will be able to connect to that PC.